# Print result by merging records in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have a table with name "**PrintWord"** and column name as **col_letter** and data in it is as follows:

```
"col_letter"
S
A
C
H
I
N
```

I would like to print the o/p from this table as:

```
SACHIN
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is there id or something?Something, that can guarantee the order of the letters in the `col_letter`.

Comment: @notulysses There is no id given there is only one column with the above characters.

Comment: Well, if there is no id, then it is impossible to print exactly the `SACHIN` string – every combination of these letters can be outputed.

Comment: @notulysses It was asked in one of the interview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @t table
(

    Name varchar(10)
)
INSERT INTO @t
SELECT 's' UNION ALL
SELECT 'a' UNION ALL
SELECT 'c' UNION ALL
SELECT 'h' UNION ALL
SELECT 'i' UNION ALL
SELECT 'n' 

SELECT DISTINCT
stuff(
(
    SELECT ' '+ [Name] FROM @t  FOR XML PATH('')
),1,1,'') 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM @t ) t
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a hard-coded version :

```
SELECT col_letter
FROM PrintWord
ORDER BY 
 CASE col_letter
 WHEN 'S' THEN 1
 WHEN 'A' THEN 2
 WHEN 'C' THEN 3
 WHEN 'H' THEN 4
 WHEN 'I' THEN 5
 WHEN 'N' THEN 6
 END
FOR XML PATH('')
```

You need an `ORDER BY` clause to guarantee the order of the letters.